# How do you use adjective or adverb to modify the gerund?

Tags: grammar

I want to figure out the situation of the gerund that should I use adjective or adverb to modify it?

I know about the gerund that can function as both noun and action. It acts like a noun.

My first question is when the gerund is single and not talking about thing just use as noun(subject ..etc..) that we use adjective or adverb?!

Example : 
(Regular)(exercising) enhance one's self-confidence.(A noun)
          OR 
(Regularly exercising)enhance one's self-confidence.(A thing)

My teacher told me the answer is the firs form. But why ?
 Could somebody tell me a bit more specifically about gerund? I couldn't sleep a few days by this confusing problem, If some one can help me and give me some example with some explaining, that I'll be very grateful!!

Comment: Your teacher is wrong. ***All three of*** *"regular exercising enhances ..."*, "*exercising regularly enhances ...*", and *"regularly exercising enhances ...*" are grammatical. To figure out which one your teacher wants requires figuring out the rules your teacher thinks they obey. We probably can't help you with that.

Comment: Sorry I made such a mistake ( my teacher told me the answer is the second ) sorry

Comment: Rather than altering your question in comments, please edit it as well.

Comment: This is way too complex a topic for the OP; they don't really understand enough to get anything out of an answer. If ever there was a OQ meant for ELL, this is it. As @Marius says, they need to fix their sentences and learn how to do the simple things before they start on the complicated ones.

Answer (score 1):

You need to fix your sentences.

Consider, for your first alternative:

1. ***Regular***  exercising enhance**s** one's self-confidence.

The "exercising" **ing-form** here is closer to a noun in meaning, thus you should use the adjective "regular." BTW, I refuse to use anymore the old classification in gerunds and participles (as does that grammar bible of Quirk et al, 1985), as I find it counterproductive.

Syntactically, "Regular exercising" is a noun phrase acting as a subject.

Now, for your other alternative:

2. *Enhance your self-confidence **by** exercising **regularly**.*
3. ***By*** exercising **regularly,** you **can enhance** your self-confidence.

The "exercising" **ing-form** in 2 and 3 is closer to a verb/action in meaning, thus you should use the adverb "regularly."

BTW, in 2 "enhance" is an imperative.

Also, syntactically "by exercising regularly" is an adverbial clause.

Comment: You really shouldn't use *"you should"* here; these choices are a matter of style and not grammar, so you should use a much weaker suggestion like *"it is better to".*

Answer (score 0):

Regular exercising and regularly exercising are two different concepts. Regular exercising could easily be interpreted as "normal" exercising or "the regular kind" of exercising, rather than exercising on a regular basis. This would explain the teacher's approval of the second option but not the first, even though both are grammatically correct (if you add the "s" in "enhances" for both).

I realize this answer is a over a year too late. -Hayley

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Although your answer is correct please provide some sources to substantiate it. Have a look at the [Help Center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) to find out about good answers.